# How do I get a MethodMirror for the current function

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Say I have

```
class RestSimulator {

@Path("/var")
void functionOne() {
  final Type type = this.runtimeType;
  final InstanceMirror instanceMirror = reflect(this);
  final ClassMirror classMirror = instanceMirror.type; 

  final MethodMirror methodMirror = ?????
  var metadata = methodMirror.metadata;
  var path = metadata.first.reflectee;

  print(path.toString()):
  }
}
```

How can I get the MethodMirror for the calling function???

[**Update**]
I meant without doing something like

```
final MethodMirror methodMirror = functions[const Symbol('functionOne')];
```

So probably the main question is: How do I get the Symbol for the calling / current function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no simple way to get a reference on the current function at runtime.

I say *simple* because you can get the name from a [StackTrace](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_core/StackTrace.html) but it's really ugly and has horrible performances...

```dart
class A {
  m() {
    var functionName;
    try {
      throw '';
    } catch(e, s) {
      functionName = parseStackTraceToGetMethod(s.toString());
    }
    print(functionName); // displays A.m
  }
}
parseStackTraceToGetMethod(String s) =>
  s.substring(8, s.indexOf("("));

main() {
  new A().m();
}
```

Comment: Uhhh - to bad! Thx for the quick reply.

Comment: There perhaps an hacky way to do that with stacktrace but it's really ugly.

Comment: I file a feature request. Something like this is necessary for method bases annotations (runtime based). I'm a bit confused why this is not already implemented.

Comment: OK - here is the feature request if someone wants to star it:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=11916&thanks=11916&ts=1374225632